# combination of np.where and if in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
   prod     S       X
   a        10      123             
   b        20      150
   b        30      140
   a        40      100

   Formula for product a and b is as follows
   a = IF(S>X, (0.6/100(S-X)),0)
   b = IF(S>X, (0.2/100(S-X)),0)
```

How can I calculate `new column` based on formula for product a and b in existing dataframe

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.where` and then `np.select`. Data from @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia.

```
a = np.where(df['S'] > df['X'], 0.6/100*(df['S'] - df['X']), 0)
b = np.where(df['S'] > df['X'], 0.2/100*(df['S'] - df['X']), 0)

df['result'] = np.select([df['prod'].eq('a'), df['prod'].eq('b')], [a, b], np.nan)

print(df)

  prod    S    X  result
0    a   10  123    0.00
1    b   20  150    0.00
2    b   30  140    0.00
3    a  140  100    0.24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` with your defined function.

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'prod':['a','b','b','a'] ,
              'S':[10,20,30,140],    
              'X':[123,150,140,100]})

     S    X prod
0   10  123    a
1   20  150    b
2   30  140    b
3  140  100    a
```

Function:

```
def func(df):
    result = 0
    if df.S > df.X:
        if df['prod'] == 'a':
            result = 0.6/100*(df.S-df.X)
        if df['prod'] == 'b':
            result = 0.2/100*(df.S-df.X)
    return result
```

Use it:

```
df.join(df.apply(func, axis=1).rename('col'))
```

Result:

```
     S    X prod   col
0   10  123    a  0.00
1   20  150    b  0.00
2   30  140    b  0.00
3  140  100    a  0.24
```

Comment: Can we use np.where and if in combination?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for speed, this will be faster if not as readable.  The where and if are accomplished through boolean indexing.

Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'prod':['a','b','b','a'] ,
                   'S':[10,20,30,140],    
                   'X':[123,150,140,100]})

print(df)

  prod    S    X
0    a   10  123
1    b   20  150
2    b   30  140
3    a  140  100
```

Code

```
# make an array to hold results
results = np.zeros(len(df))

# make arrays from df values
SX_vals = df[['S', 'X']].values
prod = df['prod'].values

# product multiplier dictionary
prod_dict = {'a': .006, 'b': .002}

# make array of S - X
sub_result = np.subtract(SX_vals[:,0], SX_vals[:,1])

# make boolean mask of subtraction results are positive
s_bigger = (sub_result > 0)

# loop through products (keys) of prod_dict
for key in prod_dict.keys():
    # mask where (S-X) > 0 and prod == key 
    mask = s_bigger & (prod == key)
    # multiply and insert into result array
    results[mask] = sub_result[mask] * prod_dict[key]

# assign result array to dataframe
df['result'] = results
```

Result

```
print(df)

  prod    S    X  result
0    a   10  123    0.00
1    b   20  150    0.00
2    b   30  140    0.00
3    a  140  100    0.24
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `pandas.Series.map` and `pandas.Series.where`

```
d = {'a': .6, 'b': .2}
df.assign(
    result=df['prod'].map(d).mul(df.S - df.X).where(df.S > df.X, 0) / 100
)

  prod    S    X  result
0    a   10  123    0.00
1    b   20  150    0.00
2    b   30  140    0.00
3    a  140  100    0.24
```